# Ionic 3 project and plugin crosswalk error

Tags: ionic-framework, crosswalk

I have a Ionic 3 project, when I run "ionic cordova run android --prod" I see

**This error:**

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ 
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\  
Subproject Path: CordovaLib null 
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and 
is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use 
Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_86b8k75dm7qqz7n5jyg9xp8kh.run(D:\project\ionic\MyProject\platforms\android\build.gradle:138) org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+ The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature. The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInp uts.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.644 secs A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+.
         > Failed to list versions for org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org /xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not GET 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_ library/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 503 from server: Service Unavailable

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+.
         > Failed to list versions for org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org /xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not GET 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_ library/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 503 from server: Service Unavailable

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

I did not recieve this error before running Ionic.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The 01.org server seems to be down. So till the servers are back online, you can ask Gradle to use the local copy of Crosswalk.

I was having the same issue from last one hour. The following solution worked for me.

Open **platforms\android\cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview\*-xwalk.gradle** file in your project directory, where * is your project name.

Look for the section -

```
dependencies {
    compile xwalkSpec
}
```

Replace it with your exact Crosswalk version which you find in Chrome Developer Tools by typing **window.navigator.userAgent** in your Developer Tools console.

So your final data would look something like this -

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4'
}
```

Comment: As a supplement, there are another two ways to get xwalk_core_library version, you can use either of them:
- 1. Go to `platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.xwalk/xwalk_core_library/`, then you can see version like "19.49.514.5"<br /> - 2. In the [Google cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nAtp2KW5upYJ:https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk), you can select a version number

Comment: The above worked for 32bit build but for 64bit build (built with --xwalk64bit flag) it creates API file without including xwalk libs

Comment: Looks like changing compile xwalkSpec to compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:22.52.561.4' + BIT_64 did the trick for 64bit build

Answer (score 8):

1 **Get crosswalk version**

There are another two ways to get xwalk_core_library version, you can use either of them:

- Go to platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.xwalk‌​/xwalk_core_library/‌​, then you can see version like `19.49.514.5`
- In the [Google cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nAtp2KW5upYJ:https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk), you can select a version number

2 **Change the gradle**

Just like @hemantv said, in file **platforms\android\cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview*-xwalk.gradle**

Change the file form

```
dependencies {
    compile xwalkSpec
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:19.49.514.5'
}
```

19.49.514.5 is the **version** get from the step one.

---

Another way, you can use this plugin temporarily:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/zhouzhongyuan/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

It just fixed this error.

Answer (score 3):

**Get Crosswalk version**

As answered by Zhongyuan Zhou, there are ways to get locally saved Crosswalk library on your project, but I prefer the following:

Go to `platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.xwalk‌​/xwalk_core_library/‌`​, then you can see version like `22.52.561.4`

**Modify `config.xml`**

Add the following into your config.xml

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library:22.52.561.4" />
```

**Compile the Android build**

Do the usual `ionic cordova build android` to build the Android APK or `ionic cordova run android` to build and run / install the Android app on an emulator or device.

Reference: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/server-error-with-crosswalk-when-running-ionic-run-android/104009/15

Comment: This is a better way to go than modifying the gradle file of a platform

Answer (score 1):

This is follow up to hemantv's answer. I was panicking but his answer saved my day, and I was able to successfully compile the app using the locally stored xwalk.

This is what I did and i hope it helps someone out there who's stuck with the same predicament.

I found out the Crosswalk version I have stored locally by running a search (including sub directorys) for "**xwalk_core_library**" in my app directory and found the file "**org.xwalk-xwalk_core_library-17.46.448.10_9bf812c8b76a44fdb31553d48df45b60d1362adc.jar**" and figured out the version I had was "**org.xwalk-xwalk_core_library-17.46.448.10**" (everything after the underscore "_" is irrelevant)

I followed the instructions and opened up the **platforms\android\cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview*-xwalk.gradle** in a text editor

found

```
dependencies {
    compile xwalkSpec
}
```

replaced with

```
dependencies {    
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:17.46.448.10'
}
```

reattempted to compile and it worked like a charm.