# Maven repository down?

Tags: maven, cordova, crosswalk

The maven repository appears to be down. Trying to fetch data from the following url results in an error:

https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml

Is this temporary or does this have to do with crosswalk no longer being developed?

```
=> Errors executing Cordova commands: 
While building Cordova app for platform Android:
Error:/Users/fullhdpixel/Projects/MyRoutes/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration    ':_armv7DebugApkCopy'.
> Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+.    Required by:    :android:unspecified
> Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+.
> Failed to list versions for org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library.
> Unable to load Maven meta-data from    https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml.
> Could not GET 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 503 from server: Service Unavailable
```

Comment: It already happens in January: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/crosswalk-error-on-android-build/77774

Comment: This is the reason why it's good to use a repository manager https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html

Answer (score 5):

There is already an open [issue](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7553) in their jira and another one on [github](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/issues/4010). I guess it should be fixed by tomorrow (monday) as none of their maintainers will work on a weekend, be patient.

As the project maintainers stated [here](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-final-release.html) there will be no new releases but the source and repos will still be available for development.

**Edit:**

You can find a workaround until the servers are up again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013326/6184203).

Comment: The workaround didn't work. A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not download xwalk_core_library.aar (org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4)
   > Could not get resource 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/23.53.589.4/xwalk_core_library-23.53.589.4.aar'.
      > Could not GET 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/23.53.589.4/xwalk_core_library-23.53.589.4.aar'. Received status code 503 from server: Service Unavailable

Comment: You have probably a different version than 23.53.589.4 saved locally, it will try to download the version you requested which is not possible because the webservice is not available. You can find which version you have locally by searching for `xwalk_core_library` in your `platforms/android` folder and then checking which version number the `.jar` has. It will be named something like this: `org.xwalk-xwalk_core_library-23.53.589.4_30c2ad80a79fe2d150584f0a8908db913f995dc4.jar`.

Comment: servers still down

Comment: Yesterday was labour-day in the US, as mentioned by one of the maintainers somewhere on github they will probably work on a fix today.

Comment: server still down :/

Comment: Yes, we all know, please have a look at the comments before yours. It does not solve the problem if you all add comment that the server is still offline.

Answer (score 0):

It seems all of https://download.01.org is down!!!

An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #30.22688343.1504522521.5cd76e0